# Making turtles wait every time

Tags: netlogo

I work in epidemic  algorithm , i use  a combination between gossip algorithm and  SIR model.
Part of what I am trying to do is to change  the  color  of  one  of   neighbors turtles and  wait 3.0 then color the other one  until all the turtles get the color green.

But my program do the  function wait  just one  time.Now  how  to make  my turtles wait  every time 3.0 ticks  then color  its  neighbor.

this the  code :

```
to setup
   clear-all
   reset-ticks 
   crt 100 
   set  color  blue
end
to go
    wait 3.0
    ask one-of out-link-neighbors with [color = blue] [ 
    set color green
    ask (link-with myself) [
    set color green - 3

  ]
]
  tick
  end
```

And  thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wait in your go command stalls the execution (in seconds). What you want to do is color it on the ticks. So, instead, you want to mod the ticks by 3 and whenever the remainder is 0, color it green.

```
to go
    if ticks mod 3 = 0
    [
        ask one-of out-link-neighbors with [color = blue] 
        [ 
            set color green
            ask (link-with myself) [set color green - 3]
        ]
   ]
```